# Delete columns based on reference worksheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a reference worksheet in a workbook that includes the worksheet name, and all headers from all files that are included in this specific workbook. I would like to use this reference worksheet to delete unwanted columns out of each respective worksheet. The process is to clean up 60 to 100 files that have been consolidated into a single workbook as individual worksheets.

The reference worksheet has all worksheet names in Column A, and headers in B through AH. Is there a way that I could highlight each record red that I want deleted and then run VBA to check the reference worksheet for which columns should be removed from each respective worksheet. I'm hoping that someone get me started or point me in a direction of a process I could reference to get this done? I've tried google but to no avail. I honestly don't even know how I would get started.

Comment: The macro recorder is super handy.  Run it and then just edit the code based off your needs.  If you get stuck on something specifc, ask that here.

Comment: Tried Google but to no avail? http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html

Comment: having a bit of difficulty understanding the flow you want; do you want to highlight the column header in the various sheets first, then go to the reference worksheet, and if it’s not in the reference sheet remove all similar headers (and columns of data) from the other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your Q correctly, work flow is:

1. Loop over reference sheet data
2. Get reference to listed worksheet
3. Loop over reference sheet row, looking for Red colour
4. For each Red colour found, search referenced worksheet header row for header text
5. If found, delete column

Sample code to get started with (there are a few assumptions in here that may need adjustment)

```
Sub DeleteHeaders()
    Dim wsRef As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rRef As Range, rRow As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rHeader As Range

    Dim RED As Long

    RED = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Set wsRef = Worksheets("NameOfReferenceWorksheet")
    ' Get reference to all data on reference sheet
    With wsRef
        Set rRef = .Range(.Cells(2, 34), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each rRow In rRef
        ' Get reference to listed worksheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Worksheets(rRow.Cells(1, 1))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Worksheet not present in workbook.  What now?
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            ' loop over the row
            On Error GoTo 0
            For Each cl In rRow.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, rRow.Columns.Count - 1)
                If cl.Interior.Color = RED Then
                    Set rHeader = Nothing
                    ' search for highlighted header text
                    With ws.Rows(1) '<-- header text in row 1
                        Set rHeader = .Find( _
                          What:=cl.Value, _
                          After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=True, _
                          SearchFormat:=False)
                        If rHeader Is Nothing Then
                            ' Header not found.  What now?
                        Else
                            ' delete entire column
                            rHeader.EntireColumn.Delete
                            ' Optional: clear colour
                            cl.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```